# Est-ce qu'on « coupe le son » de quelqu'un dans une conférence vidéo ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, informatique

Si l'on participe dans une conférence vidéo avec plusieurs personnes et on préfère ne plus entendre la voix d'un des participants, est-ce qu'on dit qu'on va « couper le son/volume » de cette personne comme on le ferait avec la télé ? ou existe-t-il peut-être une autre expression pour ce cas ?

Comment: personnellement, j'utilise l'ignoble "muter / je vais mute cette personne"

Comment: Peut-être, par plaisanterie (sinon par préciosité), pourrait-on dire qu'on *l'amuït*.

Answer (score 1):

Les conférences se faisant à l'aide de caméras et de téléviseurs, on utilise le langage de la télévision pour parler des techniques employées pour leur fonctionnement (en dehors de celles concernant les connexions entre sites).

> *On baisse le volume* pour garder un contact sonore discret, ou, *on coupe le son* pour ne pas être importuné,

... en attendant que les images nous conviennent.